# How to append all JQuery Data Columns which is retrieved by a Linq query to a Div element?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller ActionResult method which just fetches the data from server and retrieve it in JSON format and piece of Ajax and JQuery code in view where it gets JSON data and append it to a container. Previously i had a controller ViewResult which fetched the data and retrieved into a view using `@Model` property. The data were arranged in a nice way and here is picture how it looked like to the end users.
[image: Product Items Generated via view]

Can I just generate the same with JQuery Data too?
Now I'd like to append JQuery Data to my view elements but i am not able to do it. Here is my JQuery function plus Ajax call.

```
<head>
    <title>This is infinite control</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var pageSize = 10;
        var pageIndex = 0;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            GetData();

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() ==
                   $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    GetData();
                }
            });
        });

        function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Product/GetData',
                data: { "pageindex": pageIndex, "pagesize": pageSize },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                            data[i].ProductName + "</h2>");
                        }
                        pageIndex++;
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#progress").hide();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while retrieving data!");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

The above only appends the Product Name and it's not what i want.
Here is my previous view.

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    <h2>Category</h2>
                    <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            @Html.Action("Menu","Product")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
                <div class="features_items">
                    <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="product-image-wrapper" id="container">
                            <div class="single-products">
                                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { Model.ProductID })" alt="" />
                                    <h2>@Model.ProductCategory</h2>
                                    <h2>@Model.ProductPrice.ToString("c")</h2>
                                    <p>@Model.ProductName</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-overlay">
                                    <div class="overlay-content">
                                        <img src="@Url.Action("GetSecondPicture", "Product", new { Model.ProductID })" alt="" />
                                        <h2>@Model.ProductPrice</h2>
                                        <p>@Model.ProductName</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <img src="images/home/new.png" class="new" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

**Edit.**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { Model.ProductID })" alt="" />
                    <h2>@Model.ProductCategory</h2>
                    <h2>@Model.ProductPrice AFN</h2>
                    <p>@Model.ProductName</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <img src="@Url.Action("GetSecondPicture", "Product", new { Model.ProductID })" alt="" />
                        <h2>@Model.ProductPrice AFN</h2>
                        <p>@Html.ActionLink(Model.ProductName, "ProductDetails", new { Model.ProductID })</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So what do you want? All the code you have shown is to add the `ProductName` in a `<h2>` element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope i can't generate a view like the picture above with the jquery data how can i do that?

Comment: Previously i was using @HTML helpers to place data in the right place now how can i do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate the html as per your 'previous' view? - in which case you just need to append additional elements

Comment: You should look for a jquery template plugin, for example: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl - with that you can do something like:  $.tmpl( "<li>${Placeholder}</li>", { "Placeholder" : "Value" }).appendTo( "#target" );

Comment: That is all what i want, Well if i append it doesn't go in the right place and in the second hand i used to Save a picture in database using varbinary and varchar datatypes but when returning it in JSON format .ToList() the picture is not showing up? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You will find this far easier if your `GetData()` method returns a partial view and just append that to the DOM. (but for the image(s), you need to build an `<img>` tag with the correct `src` attribute)

Comment: That helped me a lot thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options you could consider. To keep it simple, I'll assume you want to generate and append the just the following html

```html
<div class="productinfo text-center">
    <img src="...." /> <!-- url to the product image -->
    <h2>....</h2> <!-- the product category -->
    <p>....</p> <!-- the product name -->
</div>
```

Option 1: Build the complete new html in ajax success call back.

```js
var container = $('#container'); // cache it

success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var image = $('img').attr('src', item.Url);
        var category = $('<h2></h2>').text(item.ProductCategory);
        var name = $('<p></p>').text(item.ProductName);
        var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('productinfo text-center').append(image, category, name);
        $("#container").append(div);
    });
}
```

Side note: You will need to generate the image url on the server and pass it in your `JsonResult`

Option 2: Create a client side template, clone it, update its properties (by referencing class names) and add it to the DOM. The template would be

```html
<div id="product" style="display:none">
     <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img class="image" src="" />
        <h2 class="category></h2>
        <p class="name"></p>
    </div>
<div>
```

and the script

```js
var container = $('#container');
var template = $('#product');

success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var clone = template.clone().html();
        clone.find('.image').attr('src', item.Url);
        clone.find('.category').text(item.ProductCategory);
        clone.find('.name').text(item.ProductName);
        container.append(clone);
    });
}
```

Option 3: (and by far the easiest and most maintainable) is to return a partial view rather than a `JsonResult` (say `_Product.cshtml`)

```cs
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper" id="container">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { id = item.ProductID })" alt="" />
                    <h2>@item.ProductCategory</h2>
                    <h2>@item.ProductPrice.ToString("c")</h2>
                    <p>@item.ProductName</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <img src="@Url.Action("GetSecondPicture", "Product", new { id = item.ProductID })" alt="" />
                        <h2>@item.ProductPrice</h2>
                        <p>@item.ProductName</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/home/new.png" class="new" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
}
```

and in the `GetData()` method

```cs
var products = // your query to get the collection of products
return PartialView("_Product", products);
```

and in the script

```
var container = $('.features_items');
function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Product")', // don't hard code your url's
        data: { pageindex: pageIndex, pagesize: pageSize },
        dataType: 'html', // change this
        success: function (html) {
            container.append(html);
            pageIndex++;
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while retrieving data!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the 3rd option as far as it looks a logical solution where is the container defined in script? actually i want to append the data in the partial view you just called _Product rather to a container.

Comment: And just one more question where this script should be placed? within the partial view?
P.S: i can't see the rest of my script code in the script section of your answer? because i want to implement ifinite scroll.

Comment: Where ever your existing `GetData()` script is - which should be in the view, not a partial (I just included the `success` bit of what needs to go in your GetData()` function to keep the answer short.

Comment: Thanks and what about the container? can't see anything like container in the view? how to append data to that partial view called _Product?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your `<div class="container">` (so it should have been `$('.container')` but unless you have multiple elements with `class="container"`, then you should be making it `<div id="container">`

Comment: That is alright, Sorry for being too lazy. do you think all the elements will go in the right place in the <div> ?

Comment: Well it will if your generate it correctly :) - i.e. all the elements inside and including your `<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">` - I just used an abbreviated sample - had a used all your code for all 3 options the answer would have been 3 pages long :)

Comment: I am talking about this here Stephen :)

Comment: @NaserDostdar, Can you please confirm where the html for each item starts - is it the `<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">` and everything in between?

Comment: Dear Stephen sorry for late reply please see my updated question you'll see that where html for each item start.

Comment: don't know why your answer edited instead of editing my question. anyhow you'll see the edit now in your answer and my question

Comment: I have updated the first part of option 3 based on your 'edit' (which I have now deleted). Will update the rest a bit later.

Comment: Thanks but where do i paste that script? and how the data will append with that script do i need to write this part or not? success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                            data[i].MainPicture + "</h2>" +
                            data[i].ProductName);
                            
                        }

Comment: See update for the complete script. Note you should change `<div class="features_items">` to `<div id="features_items">` and use `var container = $('#features_items');` (so long as they are unique, its always better to use an `id` attribute because its quicker)

Comment: gives an error : Error while retrieving data. by the way you have commented to change (html). what it should be changed to?

Comment: No, change it to `'html'` (your question had `'json'`) What error?

Comment: Error while retrieving data, this error is being generated by the script function error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103366/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-naser-dostdar).